# MariaDB -- #1305 - FUNCTION kaya.DATEADD does not exist

Tags: sql, mariadb, datediff, dateadd

I wanna select sales of daily for show on a graphic in a website and used to DATEDIFF and DATEADD functions but I get an SQL ERROR.

My table:

[image]

query of i was tried:

```
SELECT SUM(satis_fiyat) AS satis_fiyat from satis WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW() , DATEADD(DAY,-1,NOW())) ;
```

SQL ERROR:

> ```
> Hata
> SQL sorgusu: Belgeler
>
>
> SELECT SUM(satis_fiyat) AS satis_fiyat from satis WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW() , DATEADD(DAY,-1,NOW())) LIMIT 0, 25
> MySQL çıktısı: Belgeler
>
> #1305 - FUNCTION kaya.DATEADD does not exist
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maria DB uses `interval` logic:

```
curdate() - interval 1 day
```

I can't figure out what you are trying to do.  But that subtracts a day from the current date (without a time component).

Presumably, you want some comparison, such as:

```
<datecol> > curdate() - interval 1 day
```

Comment: is it possible to select the value of day from other table

Answer (score 0):

Replace `DATEADD` by `DATE_ADD`, since DATEADD doesn't exist in MariaDB and is interpreted as a stored function which doesn't exist in schema kaya.

For parameters of `DATE_ADD()` function please read the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_add/).